# Is it possible to create your own Fn+Key combinations on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout

The people who designed my laptop are idiots and as such, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> no longer translate to <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> keys.

Is there any way to do this natively in Windows?   That is, map a key combination that involves the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** No.

---

Yes, but not natively. [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) provides a powerful way to do this and other input mappings. [This thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/282-fn-key-on-a-notebook/) provides info on how to map <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about AHK, but was hoping for something simpler, preferably closer to OS level.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing that I know of outside of a custom-built keyboard driver that would be low-level enough. AHK is about as simple as you can get. :)

Comment: I was hoping for a key remap application that's tightly integrated with the OS.

Comment: Is there a Mac equivalent?

Comment: @RomanGaufman This is the best resource I could find: https://www.howtogeek.com/361724/the-6-best-tools-for-customizing-mac-hotkeys/. I have used BetterTouchTool for simple things, but I have never paid for it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no.  The <kbd>Fn</kbd> is handled by the keyboard microcontroller not the operating system.

> While it is most common for the Fn key processing to happen directly
>   in the keyboard micro-controller, offering no knowledge to the main
>   computer of whether the Fn key was pressed, some manufacturers, like
>   Lenovo, perform this mapping in BIOS running on the main CPU, allowing
>   remapping the Fn key by modifying the BIOS interrupt handler

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details